# How to create a unique name for each image and upload

Tags: php

I have a folder named uploads where when click submit, the user images are uploaded inside that folder and the images is previewed when upload complets.

If there is two images with same name , then former get replaced. I would like to create unique name for each image thus both image could be saved.

Here is my index code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
         $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({
             target: '#outputImage',
             url: 'uploadFile.php',
             beforeSubmit: function () {
                $("#outputImage").hide();
                 if($("#uploadImage").val() == "") {
                  $("#outputImage").show();
                  $("#outputImage").html("<div class='error'>Choose a file to upload.</div>");
                    return false; 
                }
                 $("#progressDivId").css("display", "block");
                 var percentValue = '0%';

                 $('#progressBar').width(percentValue);
                 $('#percent').html(percentValue);
             },
             uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {

                 var percentValue = percentComplete + '%';
                 $("#progressBar").animate({
                     width: '' + percentValue + ''
                 }, {
                     duration: 5000,
                     easing: "linear",
                     step: function (x) {
                        percentText = Math.round(x * 100 / percentComplete);
                         $("#percent").text(percentText + "%");
                        if(percentText == "100") {
                            $("#outputImage").show();
                        }
                     }
                 });
             },
             error: function (response, status, e) {
                 alert('Oops something went.');
             },
             
             complete: function (xhr) {
                 if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText != "error")
                 {
                    $("#outputImage").html(xhr.responseText);
                 }
                 else{  
                     $("#outputImage").show();
                      $("#outputImage").html("<div class='error'>Problem in uploading file.</div>");
                      $("#progressBar").stop();
                 }
             }
         });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>jQuery Ajax Image Upload with Animating Progress Bar</h1>
    <div class="form-container">
        <form action="uploadFile.php" id="uploadForm" name="frmupload"
            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="uploadImage" /> <input
                id="submitButton" type="submit" name='btnSubmit'
                value="Submit Image" />

        </form>
        <div class='progress' id="progressDivId">
            <div class='progress-bar' id='progressBar'></div>
            <div class='percent' id='percent'>0%</div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
        <div id='outputImage'></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my upload.php is

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    $uploadfile = $_FILES["uploadImage"]["tmp_name"];
    $folderPath = "uploads/";
    
    if (! is_writable($folderPath) || ! is_dir($folderPath)) {
        echo "error";
        exit();
    }
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadImage"]["tmp_name"], $folderPath . $_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"])) {
        echo '<img src="' . $folderPath . "" . $_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"] . '">';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add current time or random string,  time().$_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"] OR rand(10).$_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php Simple

Comment: @ViperTecPro Thanks but real problem starts here...then How to save the currrent name and display in <img> tag the same uploaded image inside echo.

Comment: If you want to display before saving it into db you can either use Session array or some temp variable.

Comment: @ViperTecPro I don't want to save in my database. only allow user to upload document...it works fine now when I also used time()..$_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"] inside src if <img> tag. I was confuse when saving if it takes longer time then time(), I used inside if statement and time() inside <img> remains same or different? if different then will still image preview will shows after upload?

Comment: Okay use this once $filename = time().$_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"], now use $filename in if statment and in <img> it will remain same until next submit

Comment: @ViperTecPro I am very new to this..just starting to understand....can you please edit my above upload php file as you have suggested because I tried but I definitely mistake somewhere which gives me php error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added function `makeFilenameUniq()` that is generating unique filename in upload target folder using uploaded filename.

You can change algoritm of generating an unique key in function `uniqKey()`.

```
<?php
function makeFilenameUniq($pathfile)
{
    $test = $pathfile;
    while (is_readable($test)) {
        $uniqKey = makeUniqKey();
        if (preg_match('/^(.+)\.(.+?)$/', $pathfile, $m)) {
            $test = $m[1] . "-{$uniqKey}." . $m[2];
        } else {
            $test = $pathfile . "-{$uniqKey}";
        }
    }
    return $test;
}

function makeUniqKey()
{
    return base_convert(mt_rand(0, 10000), 10, 32);
}

if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    $uploadfile = $_FILES["uploadImage"]["tmp_name"];
    $folderPath = "uploads/";

    if (!is_writable($folderPath) || ! is_dir($folderPath)) {
        echo "error";
        exit();
    }
    $pathfile = makeFilenameUniq($folderPath . $_FILES["uploadImage"]["name"]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadImage"]["tmp_name"], $pathfile)) {
        echo "<img src=\"${pathfile}\">";
        exit();
    }
}
```